# I have a text file that i want to find and delete (replace with nothing) a part that is similar but not the same

Tags: text, text-editor

I have a text file with thousands of this code below which is almost identical apart from it has a different id number. I want to find and delete all instances of this code but I do not know how to do this as find and replace requires the text to be identical. How can I do this? And what text editor on a mac can do this? Eg:

```
<br><a target='_blank' href='http://example.com/home/details/indexid/1101372'>Read More</a>

<br><a target='_blank' href='http://example.com/home/details/indexid/1101337'>Read More</a>
```

Comment: Voted to close, what language are you using?  What have you tried so far?  What specifically is not working?

Comment: There is no language being used (and i don't know any languages) it is a text file. all i have tried is search and replace as i mentioned in the topic title. im not a coder or anything so prefer if this can be done via an app with gui rather than through terminal or something else

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, delete these lines completely or perhaps delete some part of the line when you find a match?

Comment: these lines i posted are part of a much larger file. i want to delete all these lines (which are very similar but have different id's) from the main file.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use any text editor that allows you regular expression replace. E.g. Sublime Text.

Then do replace with `<br><a target='_blank' href='http:\/\/example\.com\/home\/details\/indexid\/\d+'>Read More<\/a>`

Comment: Legend!! thanks so much